# Wait for server's return message - Kotlin coroutine

Tags: android, sockets, kotlin, jobs, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using sockets for communication and outputStream.write() to send strings to server. Communication happens inside a loop and has a delay.

```
CoroutineScope(IO).launch(handler) {
while (!socket.isClosed) {
      val serverText = returnMessageString()
      socket.outputStream.write("S".toByteArray())
      .
      .
      .
      delay(delayTime)
}
```

When I get a specific string (let's say "OK") I want to wait until server sends me another string and at that time I don't want to send anything.

Comment: You can add an if condition like `if(serverText=="OK")` and read again if true.

Comment: Perhpas, but I could resend the request before getting response (if server was slow), which I don't want to. I kinda worked it around with async/await